# Update multiple array elements based on a field across multiple documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a collection with documents that each contain an array of subdocuments. Given a new array of subdocuments with the same structure as the array field in these documents, I would like to replace all array elements in the documents in my collection based on the id field of an item in my new array to whatever the value of that element is.

In other words, I want to query array elements in the collection by their id field, and replace them with the array element with the matching id field from the new array.

Example:

Collection:

```
{
 _id: "Document1",
 array: 
 [ 
   {id: 1, field2: "A", field3: "W"}, 
   {id: 2, field2: "B", field3: "X"}, 
   {id: 3, field2: "C", field3: "Y"}
 ]
},

{
 _id: "Document2",
 array: 
 [ 
   {id: 1, field2: "A", field3: "E"}, 
   {id: 2, field2: "B", field3: "F"}, 
   {id: 3, field2: "C", field3: "G"},
   {id: 4, field2: "D", field3: "H"}
 ]
},

{
 _id: "Document3",
 array: 
 [ 
   {id: 1, field2: "A", field3: "R"}, 
   {id: 2, field2: "B", field3: "S"}
 ]
}
```

New Array (contains changes to be implemented):

```
 [
   {id: 1, field2: "FIELD2_UPDATED", field3: "FIELD3_UPDATED"}, 
   {id: 3, field2: "FIELD2_ANOTHER_UPDATE", field3: "FIELD3_ANOTHER_UPDATE"}
 ]
```

This should produce the following updated collection:

```
{
 name: "Document1",
 array: 
 [ 
   {id: 1, field2: "FIELD2_UPDATED", field3: "FIELD3_UPDATED"}, 
   {id: 2, field2: "B", field3: "X"}, 
   {id: 3, field2: "FIELD2_ANOTHER_UPDATE", field3: "FIELD3_ANOTHER_UPDATE"}
 ]
},

{
 name: "Document2",
 array: 
 [ 
   {id: 1, field2: "FIELD2_UPDATED", field3: "FIELD3_UPDATED"}, 
   {id: 2, field2: "B", field3: "F"}, 
   {id: 3, field2: "FIELD2_ANOTHER_UPDATE", field3: "FIELD3_ANOTHER_UPDATE"},
   {id: 4, field2: "D", field3: "H"}
 ]
},

{
 name: "Document3",
 array: 
 [ 
   {id: 1, field2: "FIELD2_UPDATED", field3: "FIELD3_UPDATED"}, 
   {id: 2, field2: "B", field3: "S"}
 ]
}
```

Note: the new array containing the new values will contain exactly the same fields as each document's array. I'm looking to fully replace array elements here wherever the id matches.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I got your point.
If this code is your answer the c# code should be easy to implement

```
db.test.update( 
{
    'array.id' : { $in : [1, 3]} 
},
{
    $set : 
    {        
        "array.0" : {id: 1, field2: "FIELD2_UPDATED", field3: "FIELD3_UPDATED"}, 
        "array.2" : {id: 3, field2: "FIELD2_ANOTHER_UPDATE", field3: "FIELD3_ANOTHER_UPDATE"}
    }
},
{
     upsert: false,
     multi: true,     
}
);
```

**Updated:**
The solution is not a very simple update query but it works fine:

```
var toBeUpdate = [
   {id: 1, field2: "FIELD2_UPDATED", field3: "FIELD3_UPDATED"}, 
   {id: 3, field2: "FIELD2_ANOTHER_UPDATE", field3: "FIELD3_ANOTHER_UPDATE"}
 ];

db.test.find().forEach(function (item)
   {
       var array = item.array;
       for(var index = 0; index < array.length; index++)
       {           
           for(var index2 = 0; index2 < toBeUpdate.length; index2++)
           {               
               if(array[index].id == toBeUpdate[index2].id)
               {                   
                   if(toBeUpdate[index2].field1 != undefined) array[index].field1 = toBeUpdate[index2].field1;
                   if(toBeUpdate[index2].field2 != undefined) array[index].field2 = toBeUpdate[index2].field2;
                   if(toBeUpdate[index2].field3 != undefined) array[index].field3 = toBeUpdate[index2].field3;
                   break;
               }
           }
       }

      db.test.update({'_id' : item._id}, item);      
   }
)
```

Comment: In my situation, I don't know the positions in the array that need to be updated for each document. I just know that this id field must match. There is also no guarantee of order, so I can't directly specify the array index to go to.

Comment: Answer updated, but the c# query could be a challenge